# What does an xhr.status of 8 mean in IE8?

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, status, xmlhttprequest

i just want to know what is the meaning of the xhr.status 8 and what is the possible cause of that (because my ajax failed and its the status that is given to me).

Thanks

Edit : Just forget to specify that its only in IE, in Chrome or FireFox, it works (no error).

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms767625(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Are you sure it's 8. Only three-numbered HTTP status codes exists:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: There is the readyState thing (http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajaxxmlhttprequest.php), but I thought that only went up to four.

Comment: Yeah it was i thought too, but i alert(xhr.status); and it gave me 8.... and alert(xhr.statusText); gave me "Unknown".

Comment: I guess the server is returning a status code of 8? Do you control the server?

Comment: No i don't control the server.

Comment: Guess the server's trying to be mean to IE.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a library like jQuery that does a pretty good job of abstracting away browser differences?

Answer (score 0):

Same problem here.  The only fix we found was that returning less json seemed to "fix" the problem.  In our case this was acceptable, but I realize in most cases it's not.

### Edit

Also should mention we are using YUI3.  So it must not be library specific.